# Multiple ThreadPoolExecutor types refer to one task queue

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Hi I wanted to ask is there a way for multiple ThreadPoolExector types to poll tasks of a global queue? It is for an exercise out of a book which asks to design some OOP code for a Call Centre. There are three types of respondents in the callcentre and form a priority of who takes the call first.

```
public class Centre {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // initialize resources
    CallScheduler scheduler = new CallScheduler();
    scheduler.initCallQueue();

    // set up roster here
    int n_respondents = 6;
    int n_managers = 5;
    int n_directors = 3;

    scheduler.initRosterExecutors(n_respondents, n_managers, n_directors);

    // listen for incoming client requests
    try {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(SERVICE_PORT);
        System.out.println("Call Centre started.");

        for (;;) {

            Socket nxt_cal = server.accept();

            System.out.println("Received call from " + nxt_cal.getInetAddress() + ":"
                    + nxt_cal.getPort());

            scheduler.dispatchCall(nxt_cal);
            Logger.global.fine("Dispatched Call.);

            // Close the connection
            nxt_cal.close();
        }
    }
```

I'm able to dispatch the call to a queue and have only a single object type run the worker tasks. This is not as per the requirements of the center, I need to have all three types polling for available tasks. I thought I would use the ThreadPoolExecutor class with its maximumPoolSize and declare multiple types and perhaps manage with some kind of state machine.

```
public static void initRosterExecutors(int res, int man, int dir) {

    final int first_to_the_call = 1;

    res_executor =
            new RespondentExecutor(first_to_the_call, res, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    bqu, new RespondentExecutor.AbortPolicy());

    res_executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();

    man_executor =
            new RespondentExecutor(first_to_the_call, man, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    bqu, new RespondentExecutor.AbortPolicy());

    man_executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();

    dir_executor =
            new RespondentExecutor(first_to_the_call, dir, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    bqu, new RespondentExecutor.AbortPolicy());

    dir_executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();

}
```

Any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: I think the exercise is looking for you to use a _priority queue_.

Comment: Yes I thought about priority but there tasks would be ordered like in an OS, here it's just a phone call to be answered by the next available, simple enough right? I did go with my solution after reading this https://medium.com/javarevisited/thread-pools-in-java-why-use-multiple-thread-pools-in-an-application-2d06d0fa4d79.